# Making certain categories of CPT not publicly queryable

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query

I am developing a custom CMS for a client and one of the `Custom Post Types` is 'contact', these contacts are organized into categories by a `custom taxonomy`; my question is whether there is a way to **set only certain categories to be publicly queryable**. I only seem to be able to get solutions working where either make all posts of a certain post type non-public and not-publicly queryable or the other way around but not just those in a certain category.

Some additional information as suggested by @kaiser:
The custom taxonomy set up the same way normal categories are set up for posts and pages. It is just the one custom taxonomy which handles this aspect. I want to work with one custom post type only for this as i would otherwise be forced to duplicate a lot of custom fields, for example: all 'contacts' have a lot in common (contact details, etc..) but out of these 'contacts' i only want certain 'categories' to be visible and accessible from outside of admin; as an example, a contact with category 'artist' should show publicly and show up in category and sitemap pages but not those under 'providers'.

I do not wish to use multiple CPTs or multiple taxonomies if i can avoid it.

Thank you all for your input.

Comment: `category` is a hierarchical built in taxonomy. You're talking about a custom taxonomy, right? If yes, are you talking about a single one or multiple ones that are different to each other when it comes to exposing them to the public?

Comment: Already tried to split up into taxonomies having `public` argument set to `true` and others set to `false`? Btw, don't comment. Edit instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "publicly queriable" in this case? You want logged in users to be able to search but no one else? Or no search at all?

Comment: @s_ha_dum, just logged in users. ie people working for the company; there is no public sign up for clients.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you really just need a filter on `pre_get_posts` to remove the unwanted terms. Something like this, but I am not sure I understand all the conditions you need so think of it as proof of concept only.

```
function exclude_terms_wpse_117242($qry) {
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $tq = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your_tax',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(1,2,3),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        )
    );
    $qry->set('tax_query',$tq);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_terms_wpse_117242');
```

Comment: yes! how didn't i think of that!? thanks a lot @s_ha_dum, i think something like this will work. I was simply blocked for ideas. Will post the complete solution when i'm done.